# How to return a array of names in uicollectionview cells swift 4

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I am trying to insert an array of names into each of the cells as a test, but I keep getting an error when i type Example.name.text ECT. How do I return the array of names for each cell to have a name in it? Does the same work for images? My goal is to return UIImage so that each cell contains the next image in the UIImages.

```
    class TestPage: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var collectView: UICollectionView!
    var cellId = "Cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = 
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, 
        right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)

        collectView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, 
        collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectView.dataSource = self
        collectView.delegate = self
        collectView.register(Example.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: 
         cellId)
        collectView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(collectView)
        }

          let listOfNames = ["John", "Smith", "Doe"]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfNames.count
      }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
     cellId, for: indexPath) as! Example
        return cell
      }
    }

    class Example: UICollectionViewCell {

    let name: UILabel = {
       let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "This is a test"
        lb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return lb
    }()

//    let aMajorScale: UIImageView = {
//        let imgV = UIImageView()
//        imgV.image = UIImage(named: "Amajorscale")
//        imgV.contentMode = .scaleToFill
//        imgV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        return imgV
//    }()

//    let bMajorScale: UIImageView = {
//        let imgV = UIImageView()
//        imgV.image = UIImage(named: "bmajorscale")
//        imgV.contentMode = .scaleToFill
//        imgV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        return imgV
//    }()
//
//    let cMajorScale: UIImageView = {
//        let imgV = UIImageView()
//        imgV.image = UIImage(named: "c-major-scale")
//        imgV.contentMode = .scaleToFill
//        imgV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        return imgV
//    }()
//
//    let dMajorScale: UIImageView = {
//        let imgV = UIImageView()
//        imgV.image = UIImage(named: "d-major-scale")
//        imgV.contentMode = .scaleToFill
//        imgV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        return imgV
//    }()
//
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addViews()
    }

    func addViews(){
        addSubview(name)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: 
    "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: 
    ["v0" : name]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: 
     "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: [ . 
    "v0" : name]))
    }
```

Comment: Never mind I got it, but how do I set constraints so that the views fit the screen in landscape?